# Redirecting from a library

Tags: php, symfony

I'm building both a Symfony 2.6 web app and a composer library.  The composer library knows nothing of Symfony and needs to operate with other frameworks (or no framework at all).

At some point the library needs to redirect the user.  Of course it's natural in a simple library to call PHP's `header('Location: x')`.  This works fine when testing the library with straight PHP and no framework.  But within a Symfony app the controller calling the library still needs to create a `Response` object and return it.  In fact creating an empty `Response` ends up clearing the redirect.  I assume the Symfony classes create a whole new set of headers, overwriting the `Location` set in the library.

So without making my library dependent on Symfony how can it redirect the user?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an interface that your library defines and uses through dependency injection.

```
interface Redirector {
    public function redirect($location, $code);
}
```

In your library, you can then pass it as an argument to class constructors, for example:

```
class FooBar {
    private $redirector;

    public function __construct(Redirector $red) {
        $this->redirector = $red;
    }

    // ...
}
```

An implementation of that interface could use symfony's mechanisms to perform the actual redirect, and your library does not depend on any implementation.

A possible implementation could be:

```
class SimpleRedirector implements Redirector {
     public function redirect($location, $code) {
          header('Location: ' . $location, true, $code);
          die();
     }
}
```

Comment: So simple and clever.  I'm going to try it out and see how it feels.

Comment: And take a look at PSR7

Answer (score 1):

Completely agree with SirDarius.
It's a simple *Design By Contract (DbC)* pattern.
Your component is declaring the interface any app can implement in its own way.

I thought about how to implement it symfony. The Plain old PHP way of redirecting is quite easy. But a clean Symfony implementation is more difficult since the controller action must return a response object and cannot just die because the kernel have to terminate. In this case the Redirector is a stateful request scope service, saving the redirection data and providing a getResponse method.

```
<?php

class RedirectionService implements Redirector {
    private $location;
    private $code;

    public function redirect($location, $code) {
        $this->location = $location;
        $this->code = $code;
    }

    public function getResponse() {
        $response = new RedirectResponse($this->location, $this->code);
        return $response;
    }
}

// ...

public function someAction() {
    // defined in services.yml and gets our service injected
    $libraryService = $this->get('library_service');
    $libraryService->work();

    $redirectionService = $this->get('redirection_service');
    $response = $redirectionService->getResponse();
    return $response;
}
```